# how to use hash map in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have created a function to run iperf traffic. The code works as expected.the function can supports both TCP and UDP protocol.if protocol is not passed as an argument tcp is used by default. For UDP, -u is passed as argument. I have used `unless` statement for this check. I was asked to use hashmap instead of unless statement.Can some one tell me how to use hash map for this scenario?

```
sub start_iperf_on_client_forward_traffic {

    my ($self,$cli_interface_ip,$origin_interface_ip, $port,$protocol) = @_;

    unless (defined $protocol)
    {
      $protocol = "";
    }

    # start iperf3 on client. If protocol is not specified tcp protocol will be used..
    $self->{ssh}->execute( 'iperf3 ' . $protocol . ' -c ' . $origin_interface_ip . ' -B ' .
      $cli_interface_ip . ' -i ' . 2 .  ' -p ' . $port . ' -l ' . 576.
        ' -b ' . 100 . 'M ' . ' -k ' . 1000 );

    my @stdout = $self->{ssh}->stdOut();

    print  Dumper  @stdout;
}
```

function call:

```
  $self->{'traffic_obj'} =  Iperf->new(ip => "198.18.193.151" )
    $self->{'client'}   =  $self->{'traffic_obj_1'}->start_iperf_on_client_forward_traffic('9.1.1.2','8.2.0.2','7755','-u');
```

Output :

```
 $VAR1 = 'Connecting to host 8.2.0.2, port 7755';
    $VAR2 = '[  4] local 9.1.1.2 port 47105 connected to 8.2.0.2 port 7755';
    $VAR3 = '[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Total Datagrams';
    $VAR4 = '[  4]   0.00-2.31   sec  5.49 MBytes  20.0 Mbits/sec  10000  ';
    $VAR5 = '- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -';
    $VAR6 = '[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams';
    $VAR7 = '[  4]   0.00-2.31   sec  5.49 MBytes  20.0 Mbits/sec  0.279 ms  3751/9987 (38%)  ';
    $VAR8 = '[  4] Sent 9987 datagrams';
    $VAR9 = '';
    $VAR10 = 'iperf Done.';
```

Comment: What's in the hash? Alternatively, why do you want to use a hash here?

Answer (score 0):

The guts of your question comes down to this statement and question:

> I was asked to use hashmap instead of unless statement.
>   Can some one tell me how to use hash map for this scenario?

You really have not explained enough to make it possible to answer with any confidence.  Your `unless` statement simply sets the parameter to the null string if it's not passed (ie if it's undefined).  I've had a look at the `iperf3` [doco here](http://software.es.net/iperf/invoking.html), and the default behaviour if the `-u` switch is not supplied is to use TCP - so, what you have done makes sense.  Unfortunately, there's no way (that I can see, at least) to somehow "... use hashmap instead."

The best I can do is to suggest that perhaps there was a misunderstanding in the request and you were asked to use a **hashref** to pass parameters to the subroutine.

As you add more parameters to a sub (or method), it becomes increasingly difficult - and the code therefore, becomes increasingly fragile - to match the proper argument to the proper position.  The common way to solve this problem is to use *named* parameters rather than *positional* parameters as then the order is not relevant. In perl5 this usually means passing a hash of named arguments (or an array using the "fat comma" giving the same look as a hash).

So, your call would look something like this:

```
$self->{'client'}  =  $self->{'traffic_obj_1'}->
                      start_iperf_on_client_forward_traffic({
                          cli_ip    =>  '9.1.1.2' ,
                          origin_ip =>  '8.2.0.2' ,
                          port      =>  '7755'    ,
                          protocol  =>   '-u'
                       });
```

...and the opening lines of your routine would look like...

```
sub start_iperf_on_client_forward_traffic {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;
```

...but you are still going to need a similar check to see if optional parameters ("protocol" in this case) are passed;

```
my $protocol = $args->{protocol} // "" ;   # Set to "" if not passed
```

But all of this is based on speculation about what you actually meant in the first place.